# Python: split a full name "First Last", "First Middle Last," etc ... into separate variables?

Tags: python

I'm looking for the best way to write a function that takes a string in the form:

"First"
"First Last"
"First Middle Last"
"First M. Last"
"First Second Third Last"

And can return a python a list with each of the values separated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function:

```
>>> s = "First Middle Last"
>>> s.split(" ")
['First', 'Middle', 'Last']
```

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Hare is correct, however if you want to split on whitespace, loose the `" "` parameter.
The default is whitespace and is more robust:

```
>>> '   a b     c   '.strip().split(" ")
['a', 'b', '', '', '', '', 'c']

>>> '   a b     c   '.strip().split()
['a', 'b', 'c']
```